# Как организовать связи между таблицами и хранение данных в данном случае?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Как правильно организовать связи и структуру таблиц.
Есть таблица для хранения карт с уникальным id карты.
Есть таблица для хранения действий. Действия будут однотипные по названию и описанию, но разные по кол-ву полей для выбора точек, и хранения данных в каждом поле.

**Хотел связать так: id | id карты | id действия , но будет разное кол-во полей + галочка выбрано/нет. **Где лучше хранить эту информацию?****
[image: К одной карте прикреплено два действия на карте]

Comment: А как дальнейшая работа с данными идет, например поиск среди всех карт по точкам A бывает ? Задаются только точки или возможно понадобятся какие то другие виды данных ?

Comment: @Mike Далее будет выборка карты, активных действий для нее, и в зависимости от типа действия, дальнейшие операции. Поиска не будет. Но тут загвоздка в том, что полей для выбора точек может быть множество, которое задается в самом действии. Где то 0 полей где то 1 где то 3. Как хранить непонятно. Можно конечно хранить в одной ячейке таким видом: 123:123:123 или можно отдельную таблицу создать id | action_id | data_point не знаю что лучше...

Comment: Если поиска не будет, а данные для выполнения работы обычно будут браться все целиком, я бы хранил в одном поле, только не через разделитель, а сделал бы поле типа json и хранил в нем массивом или поименно, с его элементами можно работать практически так же как с полями. Или вообще рассмотрел геометрические типы данных (надо взвесить, стоят ли заморочки с ними, получаемого результата, только ради хранения возможно они избыточны)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действие можно хранить, как вы написали в вопросе, только отдельный `id` не нужен:

```
CREATE TABLE ACTION (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  map_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES MAP(id),
  selected BOOLEAN NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Для точек создайте таблицу и храните в ней точки привязанные к действию (одна точка - одна запись в таблице `ACTION_POINT`):

```
CREATE TABLE ACTION_POINT (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  action_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES ACTION(id),
  x INTEGER NOT NULL,
  y INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Я тут использовал координаты `x, y` как параметры точки для примера. Если у вас фиксированный набор точек, то вместо этого будет ссылка на запись в таблицу, в которой они хранятся.

Comment: А как координаты связаны с конкретной картой ?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю подоплеку вопроса. Так как в вопросе не раскрывается, что собой представляет точка, то тут я указал для примера какой-то способ задания (предполагается о точке хранить какую-то информацию, я предположил, что это координаты, но так же может быть ссылка на запись, как я упомянул в ответе). Я понимаю вопрос так, что проблема у автора в том, как хранить несколько точек для одного действия. Ответ об этом - в отдельной таблице.

Comment: @RomanKonoval , благодарю за ответ, только тут x y фикс, а у меня полей может быть множество. от 0 до кто его знает. Эти точки, это своего рода путь по которому будет идти бот на карте. Можно конечно хранить в одной ячейке таким видом: 123:123:123 или можно отдельную таблицу создать id | action_id | data_point не знаю что лучше...

Comment: @vovkka вы, наверно, не поняли. Для каждой точки в действии вы создаете отдельную запись в таблице `action_point`. Можете их добавить хоть 1000 штук для одного действия. Это и есть вариант с отдельной таблицей.

Comment: Я так понял действия сами по себе, карты сами по себе. одно и то же действие может быть применено к нескольким картам, только при этом точки разные будут. Хотя это лучше у автора уточнить

Comment: Если действия сами по себе, а карты сами по себе, то тогда в `action` не будет ссылки на карту, а привязка будет в другой сущности (судя по интерфейсу - quest). На хранении точек в действии это не скажется.

Comment: @Mike да, именно так